# Chainlink API call job not fulfilled - tutorial

Tags: get, solidity, chainlink

I have been trying to learn how to make a GET request using Chainlink.

I was watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ay4rXZhAefs and I used the exact same code that they used in the video and I also followed the same steps using Remix (I have my metamask (Kovan) open with enough ETH and LINK and I also funded my contract with enough LINK). However after I call requestVolumeData() the volume variable doesn't update and stays 0.

I have tried to use different networks and oracles/jobs, but I seem to run into the same issue over and over again. Any help would be appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e
     * Job ID: 29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() public {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
        jobId = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
 
    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

Comment: `PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.` It says that.

Comment: I'm not trying to use it in production. I just would like to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh okay great, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you giving some time to let the node fetch the request? When you do this example, you usually have to click the requestVolumeData() button, multiple times, waiting for the node to fulfill the request. Less than two minutes usually.

Here's another more recent version of that example contract. It's nearly the same.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {


uint256 public volume;

address private oracle;
bytes32 private jobId;
uint256 private fee;

/**
 * Network: Kovan
 * Oracle: 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e
 * Job ID: 29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8
 * Fee: 0.1 LINK
 */
constructor(address _oracle, string memory _jobId, uint256 _fee, address _link) public {
    if (_link == address(0)) {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
    } else {
        setChainlinkToken(_link);
    }
    // oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
    // jobId = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
    // fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    oracle = _oracle;
    jobId = stringToBytes32(_jobId);
    fee = _fee;
}

/**
 * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
 * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
 */
function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
{
    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    
    // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
    request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    
    // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
    // {"RAW":
    //   {"ETH":
    //    {"USD":
    //     {
    //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
    //     }
    //    }
    //   }
    //  }
    request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
    
    // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
    int timesAmount = 10**18;
    request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
    
    // Sends the request
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
}

/**
 * Receive the response in the form of uint256
 */ 
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    volume = _volume;
}

function stringToBytes32(string memory source) public pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
        return 0x0;
    }

    assembly {
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi djd. Thank you for your help! I managed to get it working using your code and this oracle/job: https://market.link/jobs/0609deab-6d61-4937-85e4-a8e810b8b272/spec